# React Native Open Android App from Background/quit

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to force my app to go from background/quit state to Foreground when receiving push notifications. Currently I have a handler to detect new incoming notifications (rnfirebase), it works perfect!

Example: Whatsapp calls. When receiving a call the phone turns on and the app opens

Is there a generic solution for this for all Android phones?

```
// index.js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler( async remoteMessage => {
      // Open app
});
```

Comment: did you find the solution?